# How to upload an APK for alpha test?

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am trying to submit my almost finished game (first app) to the alpha testing but after hours of research I still can´t.

Inside the Google Play Development console / Game services in the "Testing" tab I filled my alpha testers list but after that there is only 2 switches, there is no "APK" tab like the tutorial said and no "upload" button.

In the "publish" tab it says "ready to publish" which is odd since I haven't uploaded any APKs yet, I wonder what will it publish if I click it. I don't want make mistakes here since published apps can't be deleted as far as I know.

Finally the weirdest thing is that in the upper tab "all applications" it says "you don't have applications" while in the "linked apps" tab the game is in the list.

What am I doing wrong? I know that for someone who already publish an app this would be extremely obvious but not for me please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understand is that you are trying to upload an alpha testing APK, while you are looking into gaming services testing (which will test gaming serviecs if you play using any of the mail ids you listed there)

To upload alpha APK, see in the picture, in APK tab, you will get 'alpha testing' tab, scrolling that down, you can find a button to upload your APK.

PS - even if you make slight changes in your app listing description, 'publish' button get's activated. So nothing to worry about there.
[image]

Comment: More info: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en